# POST with arbitrary body using curl

Tags: curl

I'm using curl to test my api. I want my api to receive a POST request and return the request body.

Does anybody know how to include a body within the POST request. My api isn't handling forms, i simply want to test arbitrary JSON against my API.

I am currently using this command.

```
curl -X POST /api/route
```

How can i modify that request so that it can contain a custom body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can send arbitrary request body with --data

`curl -X POST /api/route --data ' could be anything ' --header 'Content-Type: application/json`

if you send json I would suggest to add the json content headers